# How do I convert string to float values using str functions and string indexing/slicing?

Tags: python

Title might be a little confusing but what I mean is say I have a string `s=" text, 7.4,text , 7.2,  text,7.6,"`, I want to take the numbers `7.4 7.2 7.6` out and convert them to float. How can I do this using only simple str functions such as `find()` or string indexing/slicing?

I've tried to use `replace()` to remove all the comma's and words but I run into the problem where the numbers are not spaced out: `>>7.47.27.6` so I can't convert to float; I'm not sure how to account for this as my string has inconsistent spacing. thanks

Comment: Please provide your attempt code.

Comment: is number going to be always alternately positioned between strings?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code and catch exceptions when item can not be converted to a float:

```
l = []
for item in s.split(','):
    try:
        l.append(float(item.strip()))
    except ValueError:
        continue
print(l)
#[7.4, 7.2, 7.6]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can clean the text step-by-step like so:

```py
>>> s = " text, 7.4,text , 7.2,  text,7.6,"
>>> list_of_strings = [s.strip() for s in s.split(",") if s]
>>> list_of_strings
['text', '7.4', 'text', '7.2', 'text', '7.6']
>>> list_of_strings = [s for s in list_of_strings if not s.isalpha()]
>>> list_of_strings
['7.4', '7.2', '7.6']
>>> nums = [float(num) for num in list_of_strings]
>>> nums
[7.4, 7.2, 7.6]
>>>
```

Or, putting it all together:

```py
>>> [float(elem.strip()) for elem in s.split(",") if elem and not elem.strip().isalpha()]
[7.4, 7.2, 7.6]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your **numbers are always going to be alternatively positioned between strings**, then you can utilise *slicing* as:

```
>>> s =" text, 7.4,text , 7.2,  text,7.6,"

>>> list(map(float, s.replace(" ", "").split(",")[1::2]))
[7.4, 7.2, 7.6]
```

Here's a *step by step explanation* of above code:

1. Firstly remove all the empty spaces using `my_str.replace(" ", "")`
2. Split the list based on comma `,` to get list of words using `.split(',')`
3. Slice you list from `start` as `1` and step as `2` to get the numeric strings using `[1::2]`
4. Type cast all the numbers in list using `map(float, <your_list>)`

---

However, **if numbers are randomly distributed in string**, then you can modify the above logic (using *list comprehension* this time) with additional conditional check to identify the number during iteration as:

```
>>> s =" text, 7.4, 9.5, text , 7.2, 8.6,text,7.6,"
  
>>> [float(n) for n in s.replace(" ", "").split(",") if n.replace('.','',1).isdigit()]
[7.4, 9.5, 7.2, 8.6, 7.6]
```

However you don't need indexing or slicing in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
>>> [float(n) for n in s.split(',')[1::2]]
```

Comment: What happens if you have a string like this: s=" text, 7.4,text , 7.2,  text,7.6, 3.5"?

Comment: @pakpe It would ignore the last number. However, I based my answer on the given case

Comment: Yes, it would ignore all numbers at even indexes and give a ValueError if a string was at an odd index.